# What is a shift bicluster?

Tags: machine-learning, clustering

I am reading [A comparative analysis of biclustering algorithms for gene expression data (Eren, Kemal, et al. - 2013)](http://bib.oxfordjournals.org/content/early/2012/07/06/bib.bbs032)

When explaining the Cheng and Church method, it says that:

> MSR was shown to be successful at finding constant biclusters, constant row and column biclusters, and shift biclusters.

I searched a lot but I could not find a definition of "shift biclusters".

#### Edit

I found the definition of a **perfect shift bicluster** in the book [Model-based Linear Manifold Clustering](http://books.google.it/books?id=vER5Cb9mQjgC&lpg=PA96&ots=HioonqxbHF&dq=%22shift%20bicluster%22&hl=it&pg=PA96#v=onepage&q=%22shift%20bicluster%22&f=false):

> A perfect shift bicluster (pattern) induces perfect positive correlations among a subset of features.

May I assume that shift biclusters are biclusters with a strong positive correlation (in case of perfect positive correlations, perfect shift biclusters)?